# mysqli and inner join

Tags: php, insert, mysqli, inner-join

I have a problem with this script, I select from 2 tables but I don't know how to bind the result.

I get this error :

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_result() on a non-object

This is my code : http://pastebin.com/5sShTSMC

---

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


function connect() {
    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database') or die('Der var et problem med at connecte til databasen');
    return $mysql;
}
```

Comment: What does your function `connect()` return?

Answer (score 0):

First check if your query is correct (all tables and columns exists), i think you missed something there. Use a `var_dump` to check if `$stmt` is a object or a `FALSE`.